# Converting Roman numerals to decimal

Tags: c++, roman-numerals

Could someone please point out the error(s) in the given code?  It was downvoted on Stack Overflow without any explanation, but it seems to be working fine for me:

```
int value(char roman)
{
   switch(roman)
   {
        case 'I':return 1;
        case 'V':return 5;
        case 'X':return 10;
        case 'L':return 50;
        case 'C':return 100;
        case 'D':return 500;
        case 'M':return 1000;
   }
}

int getdec(const string& input)
{
  int sum=0; char prev='%';
  for(int i=(input.length()-1); i>=0; i--)
  {
    if(value(input[i])<sum && (input[i]!=prev))
    {       sum -= value(input[i]);
            prev = input[i];
    }
    else
    {
            sum += value(input[i]);
            prev = input[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

This was the output received from the code:

> I = 1
>  II = 2
>  III = 3
>  IV = 4
>  V = 5
>  VI = 6
>  VII = 7
>  VIII = 8
>  IX = 9
>  X = 10
>  XI = 11
>  XII = 12
>  XIII = 13
>  XIV = 14
>  XV = 15
>  XVI = 16
>  XVII = 17
>  XVIII = 18
>  XIX = 19
>  XX = 20
>  XXI = 21
>  XXII = 22
>  XXIII = 23
>  XXIV = 24
>  XXV = 25
>  XXVI = 26
>  XXVII = 27
>  XXVIII = 28
>  XXIX = 29
>  XXX = 30
>  XXXI = 31
>  XXXII = 32
>  XXXIII = 33
>  XXXIV = 34
>  XXXV = 35
>  XXXVI = 36
>  XXXVII = 37
>  XXXVIII = 38
>  XXXIX = 39
>  XL = 40
>  MMMMCMXCIX = 4999
>  CM = 900
>  XC = 90

Comment: Roman Numeral converter in 855 chars :-) http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/797/roman-numeral-converter-function/828#828

Comment: I think IIX would break your code...

Comment: Your code isn't complete: it has no `main()`, nor any definition of `string`.  Is that supposed to be `std::string` from `#include <string>`?  Post something that actually compiles.

Comment: Googling Marcus Caelius tombstone reveals that he was the leader of legion XIIX. Ancient Romans were essentially pragmatic people: The reason they would not write 40 as XXXX is that it was shorter to write CO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have only [valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) Roman numbers you could use a simpler algorithms.  (i.e IIV is invalid )

> - The symbols "I", "X", "C", and "M" can be repeated three times in succession, but no more. (They may appear more than three times if
>     they appear non-sequentially, such as XXXIX.) "V", "L", and "D" can
>     never be repeated. A common exception to this is the use of IIII on
>     clocks; see below.
> - "I" can be subtracted from "V" and "X" only. "X" can be subtracted from "L" and "C" only. "C" can be subtracted from "D" and "M" only.
>     "V", "L", and "D" can never be subtracted
> - Only one small-value symbol may be subtracted from any large-value symbol.

Just (string-)replace IV by IIII, IX by VIIII and so on. Afterwards you just have to sum the numbers from left to right.

Answer (score 5):

There is a G++ compile warning (`g++ -Wall`):

```
roman.cpp: In function ‘int value(char)’:
roman.cpp:18:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

It should handle invalid inputs too. (Furthermore, it returns 9 for `IIIIIIIII`.)

Comment: Thanks. So validation checks are needed but otherwise the logic is correct?

Comment: @user1071840: To be honest, I don't know. I've checked it with 5-10 different Roman numerals and it worked fine but I don't know too much about the Roman numerals-decimal numbers conversion algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to run it but it seems to me that this algorithm won't handle "Double substractive" forms. 
Forms like XIIX instead of XVIII. 
How described on wiki – it's not typical roman number usage, but it was used in the past so the program should probably be prepared for it.

Comment: Generally, `XIIX` is not considered to be a valid roman number. Each number can only be written in one and only one way with roman numerals.

Comment: I am not expert but according to wiki there is nothing like a "valid" roman number. 
_... The "standard" forms described above reflect typical modern usage rather than a universally accepted convention. Usage in ancient Rome varied greatly and remained inconsistent in medieval and modern times..._